# JSON.stringify issue on convert an object to a JSON in Javascript #EXIF Data

Tags: javascript, php, json

Object to json is easy but don't know what happening with my code.

So i wanted to read image metadata using PHP ( most important is image created date-time ) but iPhone and other phone do not send this info with image, its working if try to upload using PC. but if image is compressed then we lost all metadata.

So it's not useful to read metadata using php then i decided to read via JavaScript and for that i am using [exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js).

for multiple upload everything is working fine but when i try to convert object to json, i am getting empty string.

Here is my code

```js
$('#ServicePhotos').change(function(){ 
    $('#err_msg').html('');    
    var objects = {};
    var lg = this.files.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < lg; i++){
        (function(file){
            var file = file;
            var file_path = file.name;
            if(file_path){
                var startIndex = (file_path.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? file_path.lastIndexOf('\\') : file_path.lastIndexOf('/'));
                var filename = file_path.substring(startIndex);
                if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
                filename = filename.substring(1); }
                //console.log('uploading image ' + filename);
            }
            EXIF.getData(file, function() {
                var exifData = EXIF.pretty(this);
                if (exifData) {
                    var allMetaData = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
                    var DateTime = EXIF.getTag(this, "DateTime");
                    objects[filename] = {'created':DateTime};
                }
            });
        })(this.files[i]);
    }
    console.log(objects); /*showing all data */
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(objects);
    console.log(myJSON); /* EMPTY ??? */
    $('#err_msg').html(myJSON);
    $('#meta_data').val(myJSON);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exif-js/2.3.0/exif.js"></script>

<input id="ServicePhotos" type="file"  />
<div id="err_msg"></div>
```

**Now here "var myJSON" is NOT showing json data**

Here is console.log

[image]

Comment: Can you show `console.log(objects)` result?

Comment: @RainDev added. Thanks

Comment: What is an exact version of exif you use?

Comment: @wscourge exif is working proerlty.   this version https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: @wscourge it's v2.3

Comment: See my edit, it does not seem like it does. I've added v2.3.

Comment: @wscourge your edit also showing empty string

Answer (score 0):

If you can't stringify it probably means your object doesn't have  **enumerable** properties. You can test if your object properties are [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable), if true, you should be able to use `JSON.stringify()`

From **MDN Web Docs** (https://developer.mozilla.org):

"*All the other Object instances (including Map, Set, WeakMap, and WeakSet) will have only their enumerable properties serialized.*"

From documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Then why this code working ? 

<script>
var obj = {};
for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
  obj[x+".jpg"] = {'created':x+1};
}
console.log(obj);
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(myJSON);
</script>

Comment: Because your object properties are enumerable: Check it like  for(var prop in obj)
console.log(obj.propertyIsEnumerable(prop));

Comment: That's fine but i want solution. i want to send file name and created date-time in key=>value at server. that's all...  how to do ?